# PHP Transform mixed sequential and associative array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sequential, associative

I would like to build $goal array from $initial only. Any ideas? Thank you

Edit : the question could be how to differentiate associative parts from sequential ones.

```
$intial=[
    "one",
    "two"=>"myTwo",
    "three",
    "four"=>"myFour"
];
$goal=[
    "one"=>null,
    "two"=>"myTwo",
    "three"=>null,
    "four"=>"myFour"
];
```

Comment: they are both separate arrays ? ````foreach($goal as $key=>$val){ echo $key .' == '. $val . '<br>'; }```` or just ````var_dump($goal);````

Comment: Hi. I have only  $initial array and I need to build $goal from it.

Comment: you would have to check if the value exists or isset something like: ````$goal = []; foreach($initial as $key => $val){ if(isset($val){ $goal[$key] = $val }else{ $goal[$key] = $key; } }````

Comment: This is not working, outputing Array ( [0] => one [two] => myTwo [1] => three [four] => myFour )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'sequential' parts will have numeric keys, so if your 'associative' keys will always be strings, you could use that to differentiate:

```
$goal = [];
foreach ($initial as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        $goal[$value] = null;
    } else {
        $goal[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$goal = []; 
 foreach($initial as $key => $val){ 
   if(isset($val){ 
     $goal[$key] = $val; 
   }else{ 
      $goal[$key] = $key; 
   } 
  }
```

Comment: This is not working, outputing Array ( [0] => one [two] => myTwo [1] => three [four] => myFour )